# Horizon Access - Unable to create a new session key. It is likely that the cache is unavailable

Tags: openstack, openstack-horizon, microstack

I tried to access Horizon as recommended [here](https://microstack.run/docs/), through the IP `10.20.20.1` and `admin` user, and received the following runtime error:

```
Request Method: | POST
-- | --
http://10.20.20.1/auth/login/
2.0.13
RuntimeError
Unable to create a new session key. It is likely that the cache is unavailable.
/snap/microstack/196/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/cache.py in create, line 51
/snap/microstack/196/bin/uwsgi
3.6.9
['.',  '',  '/snap/microstack/196/usr/lib/python36.zip',  '/snap/microstack/196/usr/lib/python3.6',  
'/snap/microstack/196/usr/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',  '/snap/microstack/196/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages',  
'/snap/microstack/196/lib/python3.6/site-packages',  '/snap/microstack/196/lib/python3.6/site-packages/openstack_dashboard']
Mon, 17 Aug 2020 12:42:48 +0000
```

The expected result would be a successful login.

Comment: Is memcached up and running? It sounds like that's missing or down.

Comment: @eblock , I really do not know, as I just followed the documentation and it does not mention something related to memcached...

Comment: I'm not familiar with microstack at all, so I'm just guessing from my manual installation of all openstack services.

Comment: I stopped and started the memcached service, but the problem continues...

Comment: Does [this](https://ask.openstack.org/en/question/91657/runtimeerror-unable-to-create-a-new-session-key-it-is-likely-that-the-cache-is-unavailable-authorization-failed-the-request-you-have-made-requires/) help? [Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/openstack-manuals/+bug/1585473) is another similar description.

Comment: @eblock , the first link I had seen. I did not try the 0.0.0.0, because of the warning message about security, but I changed to the suggested IP (10.20.20.1) and it did not work. Also, I enabled the `CACHES` section as the second link suggests, but without the `SESSION_ENGINE`, and it did work too...

Comment: I just saw now that the file was not saved. Even using `sudo`. The first time this happens: I cannot save a text file with or without `sudo` using the nano editor.

Answer (score 1):

Check on which address Memcached is running. With the command:

```
systemctl status memcached
```

And set that IP address in the **local_settings.py** mine it's located in /etc/openstack-dashboard/local_settings.py

```
CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache',
        'LOCATION': '192.168.122.2:11211',
    },
}
```

Comment: Remember that if you put a host name, make sure that the host name points to the Memcached interface.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. For me, adding `-l 10.20.20.1` (below `-l 127.0.0.1`) in /etc/memcached.conf and restarting memcached with `systemctl restart memcached` seemed to do the trick.